# Count of XML nodes in Java

Tags: java, xml

From this XML response how can I get the number of  tags in Java? I tried using `NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("item"); System.out.println(list.getLength());` but it's not giving the desired count i.e 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns6:ReadPersonReturn xmlns:ns2="urn:co-base.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns1="urn:cs-base.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns4="urn:co-meta.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns3="urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns5="urn:task-base.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns6="urn:cs-ors.informatica.mdm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns6:ReadPersonReturn">
       <ns6:object xmlns:ns0="urn:cs-rest.informatica.mdm">
          <ns3:Person label="Person">
             <ns2:rowidObject>28</ns2:rowidObject>
             <ns3:firstNM>John</ns3:firstNM>
             <ns3:lastNM>Cook</ns3:lastNM>
             <ns3:Phone firstRecord="1" pageSize="10" searchToken="SVR1.28WC2">
                <ns3:item label="Phone">
                   <ns2:rowidObject>1</ns2:rowidObject>
                   <ns3:phoneNumber>123456789</ns3:phoneNumber>
                </ns3:item>
                <ns3:item label="Phone">
                   <ns2:rowidObject>2</ns2:rowidObject>
                   <ns3:phoneNumber>11223344</ns3:phoneNumber>
                </ns3:item>
             </ns3:Phone>
          </ns3:Person>
          <ns3:changeSummary logging="false" xmlns:sdo="commonj.sdo"/>
       </ns6:object>
    </ns6:ReadPersonReturn>
```

Comment: A note on terminology: the number of tags will normally be twice the number of nodes, because element nodes generally have a start tag and an end tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document has namespaces.  You need to use a different API call:

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm", "item");
```

If you don't care about the namespace and you are sure `<item...>` does not occur in the other namespaces, you can use `"*"` instead.